# Conditional Operator in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Script which will check for multiple OS version (like example 6.1 , 5.1 etc.) and if the Computer is 'Enabled = True' in AD ; then it will return the entire Computer list along with it's properties in an excel sheet.

When I am using only a single condition to check for the OS version then the script works fine. The script which runs fine is as follows :-

```
import-module ac*

Get-ADComputer -filter { OperatingSystemVersion -Like '*6.1*' -and Enabled -eq "true"} -SearchBase 'OU=MIComputers,OU=MI,dc=imaje,dc=intra' -Properties '*' | Select Name,OperatingSystem,Status, OperatingSystemVersion, `
LastLogonDate,CanonicalName | Export-Csv -NoType "C:\Temp\B2.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

However, the issue is when I am using the 'and' condition to check for multiple OS version then the script returns a blank excel sheet.

```
import-module ac*

Get-ADComputer -filter { OperatingSystemVersion -Like '*6.1*' -and OperatingSystemVersion -Like '*5.1*' -and Enabled -eq "true"} -SearchBase 'OU=MIComputers,OU=MI,dc=imaje,dc=intra' -Properties '*' | Select Name,OperatingSystem,Status, OperatingSystemVersion, `
LastLogonDate,CanonicalName | Export-Csv -NoType "C:\Temp\B2.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

Can anyone please point me to what I am doing wrong here and how this can be rectified ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use two times the same condition 'OperatingsystemVersion', unless you put -OR between them.

If you search for both 5.1 and 6.1 for the same Computer Object, you will get no result.

```
import-module ac*

Get-ADComputer -filter { OperatingSystemVersion -Like '*6.1*' -OR OperatingSystemVersion -Like '*5.1*' -and Enabled -eq "true"} -SearchBase 'OU=MIComputers,OU=MI,dc=imaje,dc=intra' -Properties '*' | Select Name,OperatingSystem,Status, OperatingSystemVersion, `
LastLogonDate,CanonicalName | Export-Csv -NoType "C:\Temp\B2.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer. The script works fine now. Also I had a query. The Script takes more than 20 minutes to run. Is this because of the number of machines in the AD or can the script be optimized ?

Comment: Yes, it could be. you could try to assign a variable to your search and then check how many records do you have with the Count method. 

$a = Get-ADComputer -filter { OperatingSystemVersion -Like '6.1' -or OperatingSystemVersion -Like '5.1' -and Enabled -eq "true"} -SearchBase "OU=EUD_DB7,DC=db,DC=demo" 

$a.count

Comment: Generally, @AvikChowdhury, you want to filter on the left, as early as you can.  You're doing that in this code.  However, the search itself *is* going to take a long time.  You're looking for every computer with an OS like 6.1 or 5.1, which means a wildcard search.  Thats going to take a while.